# How to Upgrade Flutter In Project IDX

Tags: flutter, dart, idx

I am facing issue with setting up my flutter app into project idx getting and git related error while
upgrading the flutter versoion

```
flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.2.

Because carconnect requires SDK version >=3.2.3 <4.0.0, version solving failed.
```

after running `flutter upgrade` i got following error

```
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
error: cannot open '.git/FETCH_HEAD': Read-only file system
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

i also tried deleting the .git file from the project but still getting the same

tried

`flutter upgrade --force`

but nothing changed

Comment: Did you try to uninstall and install Flutter again?

Comment: `flutter upgrade`isn't supported yet. Check this [discussion](https://idx.uservoice.com/forums/953956-general/suggestions/47559902--flutter-upgrade) for more information and updates.

Comment: @belinda.g.freitas not getting installed after uninstalling because it doesnt have unzip or apt or sudo

Comment: @VictorEronmosele Didn't found anything at the link you provided

Comment: @hetsaraiya, in the link an IDX team member said: "we are working on a more streamlined story here. We hope to share some updates in the near future." when a user asked for how to upgrade Flutter in IDX.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find to work the command `flutter upgrade`,
but I can change flutter SDK version with nix setting.

1. open `'.idx/dev.nix'` file.
2. edit channel to "unstable"

   `channel = "unstable";`
3. edit packages name from `pkgs.flutter` to `pkgs.flutter316`

   ```
   packages = [
       pkgs.flutter316
       pkgs.nodePackages.firebase-tools
       pkgs.jdk17
    ];
   ```
4. Click right bottom button - `Rebuild Environment`

Now it's SDK 3.16.7 version. I don't know how to choose exact 3.16.3 SDK version.

There's few other versions such as flutter319, flutter313, etc.

You can check some other versions with [this link](https://search.nixos.org/packages?channel=unstable&show=flutter&from=0&size=50&sort=relevance&type=packages&query=flutter).

Comment: Now, IDX has updated. You can use 'flutter upgrade' command directly.